# Why is this integral bounded for finite measures?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, with $\mu$ a finite measure. Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Suppose $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{|X|>n}|X|~\text{d}\mathbb{P}=0$$

In proving the integrability of $X$, the following step is made. Take $N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\int_{|X|>N}|X|~\text{d}\mathbb{P}\leq 1$.
Now:

$$\int_\mathbb{R}|X|~\text{d}\mathbb{P} = \int_{|X|>N}|X|~\text{d}\mathbb{P}+\int_{|X|\leq N}|X|~\text{d}\mathbb{P} \leq 1 + N\cdot\mu(|X|\leq N)$$

Where $\mu(|X|\leq N) := \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:|X(\omega)|\leq N\})$. Why is it that the second integral can be bounded by $N\cdot\mu(|X|\leq N)$?
My first thought was by somehow using the Markov inequality, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, for the domain of integration in the second integral we have that $|X| \leq N$ everywhere. So clearly, $\int X_{|X| \leq N} d\mathbb P \leq \int_{|X| \leq N} N d\mathbb P = N \int_{|X| \leq N} d\mathbb P = N \mu\{|X| \leq N\}.$

Comment: Oh you're complete right, I somehow didn't realize that $|X|\leq N$ everywhere...

Comment: It's chill, you were just overthinking it, it happens